# GTK+ helper program

Tags: gtk, helper

A non-root user should only have permission to write to its program folder. Everyone can execute the program, and new files can be created, modified only by the non-root user who owns the program. GTK+ doesn't let setuid and needs a helper program. I want to use polkit to achieve this in GTK+.

Could not find any examples in C. I have pkactions and other related files, however, the program needs to register it with polkit. The docs doesn't give me a clear picture of how to achieve this from API or I could not understand.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Below are some of the links that I tried to refer to, but without much succes.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/index.html
https://greyok.github.io/simple-polkit-tutorial.html

Comment: I can't see exactly why from your example you need to use setuid and why this cannot be accomplished by appropriate set of permissions on your filesystem.

Comment: I do not want to use sticky bits to allow access others to write and modify the files, if that is what you mean Paul. I do not want to setuid, I only want to use polkit and pkexec.

Comment: Mmm... In all filesystems I know, creating and editing are grouped together permission wise.

Answer (score 2):

Under the well reasoned advice of https://www.gtk.org/setuid.html you should not use setuid in your gtk application. It advises communication from Gtk to a setuid backend via a pipe with the input validated for trust by the setuid program. This also has the advantage of decoupling your UI and backend nicely and you won't need to do your setuid program in C (though Gtk has a plethora of bindings) or with a knowledge of Gtk at all.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Would you have any set of examples?

Comment: No sorry, its some very specific requirements you have.